# Where can I get an updated version of JOGL? Possibly working with NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jogl

I need possibly detailed instructions on how to get an updated version of JOGL, and help in configuring NetBeans (6.9.1) to run with it (and give code hints and such).
Please bear in mind that I am no expert in the field of Java, and it's just been a few weeks since I started, so the most detailed instructions possible would be best :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOGL has moved to the Kenai project.  JOGL 1.1.0 is pretty stable.  If you want the new OpenGL 3 features, you'll need to download the beta 2.0 version here...

http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-2.0-beta10/

Getting JOGL setup is fairly simple.  First, you'll need your build environment to include the jar files you unzip.  You can do this in netbeans by right-clicking on your project and adding the jars to your class path settings.  This will also add code completion from that API.

Since JOGL also ships with native code to work with the OpenGL drivers, you will need the JVM to point the compiled libraries.  Specifically, you need to tell netbeans to point the java.library.path to the directory holding the library files.  If you get an UnsatisfiedLinkError, you're not linking to those native files correctly.

You'll find an example of doing that here.
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic11122.html

Once you get that setup, there is a netbeans OpenGL pack, which provides some OpenGL widgets to the matisse gui builder.  It's not completely necessary, but kind of nice.

Keep in mind, though, JOGL 2.0 is still in beta, and if you don't absolutely need OpenGL 3, you should stick with the 1.1 build provided on that site.

Comment: I just spent 3 days in jogl 2.0 beta hell and this answer finally helped. I'm using a Mac and kept getting the UnsatisfiedLinkError in java.library.path. Finally I put all the compiled libs into /Library/Java/Extensions and what do you know, the JVM could see them. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

JOGL briefly moved to Kenai, but it's now at http://jogamp.org/. If you want the last stable version of JOGL (1.1.1a), you should get it at http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.1a/. If you want the new 2.0 beta version, you should get it at http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/. The current autobuild is in "jogl-b207-2010-11-09_04-31-10/build" in that directory.

I haven't seen a NetBeans tutorial for JOGL 2.0 , but there are some for Eclipse at http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/tutorial-a-cross-platform-workbench-program-using-java-opengl-and-eclipse/ and https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorials.